# Grails: updating hibernate after externally loading data

Tags: database, hibernate, grails

I have a grails application. I'd like to load data into the underlying database with something external to grails, perl, specifically. I know I have to update the hibernate sequence after external data loading, otherwise on the next create object in grails, hibernate throws an exception; but is there anything else I need to update? Do I have to clear the hibernate cache, for instance? This would seem to be a very common issue, but there's no discussion of it in the grails docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found this 
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Accessing-the-2nd-level-cache-to-allow-it-to-be-cleared-via-a-controller-or-service-td1390985.html

Hibernate has APIs for this. You can get the query cache via sessionFactory.getQueryCache() and clear it using

```
   sessionFactory.queryCache.clear()
```

You can access a cache for a domain classes using its full class name, e.g.

```
   def cache = sessionFactory.getSecondLevelCacheRegion('com.foo.bar.Book')
```

and clear it via

```
   sessionFactory.getSecondLevelCacheRegion('com.foo.bar.Book').clear()
```

You can also call evict() on the sessionFactory for an entire class

```
   sessionFactory.evict(com.foo.bar.Book)
```

or for an individual instance

```
   sessionFactory.evict(com.foo.bar.Book, 42)
```